# How to integrate the payment gateway using its API and create the payment processing in the marketplaces like Aliexpress?

Tags: paypal, stripe-payments, payment-gateway

I was searching for a while, what is the logic behind it? Of course, there are some ideas comes to my mind:

1) Take the payment from the client to my credit card using payment gateway API

2) The client confirms he received the order.

3a) Then I will send the money to the merchant using direct payment API from my card to the merchant's card

3b) If the client will not be satisfied with the quality of the product, or will not receive the payment, I will send back from my card to the customer's card.

There are tonnes of commissions while sending the money back and forth, and I think this is no the best practice. Could someone explain or suggest me, how should I implement it, on the example of popular payment gateway: Paypal or Stripe for example

Answer (score -1):

This is a really general question, but I think you want something like [Connect](https://stripe.com/docs/connect)
to help with this.